# facebook pay dialog not showing local currency dialog

Tags: facebook, payment

facebook pay dialog shows credits only, when i click on buy credits rather then it should goto next dialog where it should ask me the payment options it just says your purchase is successful.  not sure what i'm doing tried everything but it's not working.

here is my javascript function

```
function buy_tokens(p){

FB.init({appId: "myappid", status: true, cookie: true});

    var obj = {
    method: 'pay',
    action: 'buy_item',
    order_info: {'item_id': 'tokens', 'price':p},
    dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}
    };
    //FB.ui(obj, js_callback);
   FB.ui(obj, function(paydata) {
       // response back        
   });

}
```

here is my callback.php

```
<?php

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => APP_ID,
'secret' => SECRET,
'cookie' => true,  
));

$api_key = 'appid';
$secret = 'app secret';

// prepare the return data array
$data = array('content' => array());

//parse signed data
$request = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $secret);

if ($request == null) {
// handle an unauthenticated request here
}

$payload = $request['credits'];

// retrieve all params passed in
$func = $_REQUEST['method'];
$order_id = $payload['order_id'];


function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 // decode the data
$sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
$data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
return null;
}

// check sig
$expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
return null;
}

return $data;
}


function base64_url_decode($input) {
return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}


if ($func == 'payments_status_update') {
$status = $payload['status'];

// write your logic here, determine the state you wanna move to
if ($status == 'placed') {
$next_state = 'settled';
$data['content']['status'] = $next_state;
}
// compose returning data array_change_key_case
$data['content']['order_id'] = $order_id;
} else if ($func == 'payments_get_items') {
// remove escape characters  
$order_info = stripcslashes($payload['order_info']);
$item_info = json_decode($order_info, true);
//Per the credits api documentation, 
//you should pass in an item reference
// and then query your internal DB for the proper 
//information. Then set the item 
//information here to be returned to facebook 
//then shown to the user for confirmation.

if($item_info['price']=='0.69'){
    $tokens = 150000;
}elseif($item_info['price']=='1.49'){
    $tokens = 350000;
}elseif($item_info['price']=='2.49'){
    $tokens = 600000;
}elseif($item_info['price']=='3.99'){
    $tokens = 1000000;
}

$fb = $facebook->api('/me/?fields=currency'); 
$credit = round($item_info['price']*$fb[currency]        ['currency_exchange_inverse']*$fb[currency]['currency_offset']*$fb[currency] ['currency_exchange']);
//  $symbol = array('GBP'=>'£','EUR'=>'€','USD'=>'$');


if ($item_info['item_id'] != "") {
$item['title'] = $tokens.' Tokens ';
$item['price'] = $credit;
$item['description']= 'You will get '.$tokens.' Tokens';
$item['image_url']='url';
$item['product_url']='url';
}
//for url fields, if not prefixed by http:,
//prefix them
$url_key = array('product_url', 'image_url');  
foreach ($url_key as $key) {
if (substr($item[$key], 0, 7) != 'http://') {
$item[$key] = 'http://'.$item[$key];
}
}
$data['content'] = array($item);
}

// required by api_fetch_response()
$data['method'] = $func;
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true} parameter will only work if you are not using a test account for the purchase. Try it with a facebook account that is not listed as a Payments Tester in your app's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes try it with any other account that is not admin/developer of the application and you will see the payment dialog with paypal and other payment options